# ¿Cómo puedo validar si el valor de un input es igual a alguno de estos 3 valores?

Tags: javascript, validación, entrada

```
if ($("#solicitud").val() ==2 && $("#prioridad").val() !=500  ){


            statSend = false;

            $( "#dialog-modal-datos" ).openModal();

            return false;
        }
```

este codigo solamente me da la opción de validar si el 2do campo "prioridad" no es igual a 500
¿cómo podria agregar mas valores a esa condicion? deseo agregar los valores 1000, 1500, 2000 , que si se cumple me muestre el modal.

Lo intente con un else if pero al cumplirse la primera condicion siempre me arroja el primer modal y no el segundo que quiero.

```
else if ($("#prioridad").val() != 1000) {

            statSend = false;

            $( "#dialog-modal-prioridad2" ).openModal();

            return false;
          }
```

tengo que hacerlas por separado?

Comment: Debes aplicar la condicional `OR (||)` a tu if

Comment: La condición de "$("#solicitud").val() ==2" se tiene que cumplir siempre o sólo en combinación con "$("#prioridad").val() !=500"?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer un switch case dependiendo del valor de "prioridad"

```
    valor = $("#prioridad").val();

    switch(valor) {
    case 500: 

        //Modal que quieres si sale 500
        break;

    case 1000:

       //Modal que quieres si sale 1000
       break;

    case 1500:

       //Modal que quieres si sale 1500
       break;

    case 2000:

       //Modal que quieres si sale 2000
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes utilizar el OR en el condicional del primer IF y no tendras la necesidad de añadir el ELSE IF

```
if ($("#solicitud").val() ==2 && ($("#prioridad").val() !=500 || $("#prioridad").val() != 1000 || $("#prioridad").val() != 1500 || $("#prioridad").val() != 2000) ){
            statSend = false;
            $( "#dialog-modal-datos" ).openModal();
            return false;
}
```